# Codeception and PHPUnit compatibility

Tags: phpunit, codeception

i get this error when i run "codecept run"

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Codeception\Test\Unit::getDependencies() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getDependencies(): array in C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Test\Unit.php on line 14

Call Stack:
    0.2039     395560   1. {main}() C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:0
    0.2046     416240   2. require_once('C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\autoload.php') C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:7
    0.2498    1926160   3. include_once('C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\shim.php') C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\autoload.php:24
    0.2545    2070368   4. spl_autoload_call() C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\shim.php:23
    0.2545    2070408   5. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\shim.php:23
    0.2549    2070520   6. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
    0.2552    2092160   7. include('C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Test\Unit.php') C:\www\taxi\public\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444
```

Composer json

```
 "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8",
 "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.2@stable",
 "codeception/codeception": "^2.4",
 "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "4.*",
 "lucatume/wp-browser": "~1.21",
 "codeception/phpunit-wrapper": "^7.1"
```

I have a compatibily issue?

Comment: yes, current version is incompatible with phpunit 7.2

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5092

Comment: how did you solve this issue. was anyone able to solve?

Comment: it seems PHPUnit 7.2 and Codeception 2.4 are incompatible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit 7.2 and Codeception 2.4 are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624616/phpunit-7-2-and-codeception-2-4-are-incompatible)