# PHPUnit 7.2 and Codeception 2.4 are incompatible

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, codeception

Trying to install CodeCeption with Laravel framework 5.6

I am getting this error.

Steps i followed to install are
1. composer require codeception/codeception --dev
2. php ./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap

The error i am getting is

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Codeception\Test\Unit::getDependencies() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getDependencies(): array in /vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Unit.php on line 14
```

Can someone tell how to fix this or downgrade and get it work with Laravel 5.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Codeception/Test/Unit.php line no 133, change the getDependencies function to have a array return type. `: array`

After the change the getDependencies function should look like this.

```
public function getDependencies(): array
{
    $names = [];
    foreach ($this->getMetadata()->getDependencies() as $required) {
        if ((strpos($required, ':') === false) and method_exists($this, $required)) {
            $required = get_class($this) . ":$required";
        }
        $names[] = $required;
    }
    return $names;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This was just [fixed in `codeception/codeception` version 2.4.5](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4/CHANGELOG-2.4.md#245), so run `composer update`, and the error should no longer be happening.

---

From the changelog (**emphasis** mine):

> 2.4.5
>
> - **Fixed PHPUnit 7.2 compatibility.**
> - Introduced **RunBefore** extension to execute scripts before running tests. See #5049 by @aashmelev.
> - [Db] Added two options for MySQL by @bangertz
>
>   - `ssl_cipher` - list of one or more permissible ciphers to use for SSL encryption
>   - `ssl_verify_server_cert` - disables certificate CN verification
> - [Db] Always disconnect before connect when `reconnect` is set. By @ashnazg
> - [Db] More explicit PDO closing upon destruction and close opened transactions by @ashnazg.
> - [Recorder Extension] Improved error logging by @OneEyedSpaceFish. See #5101
> - [Lumen] Fixed file uploads via REST module. By @retnek.
> - Fixed: function getMetadata() may not exist, results in fatal error. See #4913 by @marcovtwout